# Having trouble using data retrieved with json in javascript, cannot sort the array

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to sort out the data I retrieved from an api with javascript.

Code :

```
function getResults() {
    var url = $.getJSON("http://api.api.com&leagues=SOCENGPRE&lang=en&format=jsonp&callback=?", function(jsondata){;
        for(var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++)
            for(var id in jsondata[i]) {
                console.log("ID - " + id);
                console.log("TEAM - " + jsondata[i][id].home_team);
            }
    });
}
```

Example of data retrieved :

```
{
    "SOCENGPRE": {
        "league_name": "Barclays Premier League",
        "league_phid": null,
        "league_type": null,
        "fixtures": [
            {
                "id": "64714",
                "code": "SOCENGPRE",
                "event_slug": "west_ham-tottenham-1401290",
                "home_team": "West Ham",
                "away_team": "Tottenham",
            },
            {
                "id": "64711",
                "code": "SOCENGPRE",
                "event_slug": "manchester_u-sunderland-1401286",
                "home_team": "Manchester U",
                "away_team": "Sunderland"
            }
```

But using my code I cannot seem to get the results I am wanting.

I want to print out every games ID and Home Team. Any insights on why is my code not working? Thank you very much in advance!

UPDATE: I have removed the extra semi-colon but it's still not printing the data for me.
UPDATE 2: Regarding the requests for the URL. When I call it in a browser I get this huge result

```
?({"SOCENGPRE":{"league_name":"Barclays Premier League","league_phid":null,"league_type":null,"fixtures":[{"id":"64714","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"west_ham-tottenham-1401290","start":"1399117500","home_team":"West Ham","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t523.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Tottenham","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t498.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64711","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"manchester_u-sunderland-1401286","start":"1399125600","home_team":"Manchester U","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t20790.png","home_team_short":"Man U","away_team":"Sunderland","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t382.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64712","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"stoke-fulham-1401288","start":"1399125600","home_team":"Stoke","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t389.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Fulham","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t379.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64706","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"aston_villa-hull-1401282","start":"1399125600","home_team":"Aston Villa","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t380.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Hull","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t511.png","away_team_short":"Hull","phid":null},{"id":"64710","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"newcastle-cardiff-1401287","start":"1399125600","home_team":"Newcastle","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t385.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Cardiff","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t524.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64713","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"swansea-southampton-1401289","start":"1399125600","home_team":"Swansea","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t384.png","home_team_short":"Swansea","away_team":"Southampton","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t8482.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64709","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"everton-manchester_c-1401285","start":"1399134600","home_team":"Everton","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t499.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Manchester C","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t383.png","away_team_short":"Man C","phid":null},{"id":"64707","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"arsenal-west_bromwich-1401281","start":"1399206600","home_team":"Arsenal","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t30773.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"West Bromwich","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t816.png","away_team_short":"West Brom","phid":null},{"id":"64705","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"chelsea-norwich-1401283","start":"1399215600","home_team":"Chelsea","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t497.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Norwich","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t1438.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64708","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"crystal_palace-liverpool-1401284","start":"1399316400","home_team":"Crystal Palace","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t518.png","home_team_short":"C. Palace","away_team":"Liverpool","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t381.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64679","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"manchester_u-hull-1401252","start":"1399401900","home_team":"Manchester U","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t20790.png","home_team_short":"Man U","away_team":"Hull","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t511.png","away_team_short":"Hull","phid":null},{"id":"64630","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"manchester_c-aston_villa-1401198","start":"1399488300","home_team":"Manchester C","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t383.png","home_team_short":"Man C","away_team":"Aston Villa","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t380.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64621","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"sunderland-west_bromwich-1401189","start":"1399488300","home_team":"Sunderland","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t382.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"West Bromwich","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t816.png","away_team_short":"West Brom","phid":null},{"id":"64719","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"manchester_c-west_ham-1401296","start":"1399816800","home_team":"Manchester C","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t383.png","home_team_short":"Man C","away_team":"West Ham","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t523.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64717","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"liverpool-newcastle-1401295","start":"1399816800","home_team":"Liverpool","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t381.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Newcastle","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t385.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64720","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"norwich-arsenal-1401297","start":"1399816800","home_team":"Norwich","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t1438.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Arsenal","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t30773.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64715","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"fulham-crystal_palace-1401293","start":"1399816800","home_team":"Fulham","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t379.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Crystal Palace","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t518.png","away_team_short":"C. Palace","phid":null},{"id":"64722","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"sunderland-swansea-1401299","start":"1399816800","home_team":"Sunderland","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t382.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Swansea","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t384.png","away_team_short":"Swansea","phid":null},{"id":"64723","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"tottenham-aston_villa-1401300","start":"1399816800","home_team":"Tottenham","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t498.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Aston Villa","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t380.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64724","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"west_bromwich-stoke-1401301","start":"1399816800","home_team":"West Bromwich","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t816.png","home_team_short":"West Brom","away_team":"Stoke","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t389.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64718","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"hull-everton-1401294","start":"1399816800","home_team":"Hull","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t511.png","home_team_short":"Hull","away_team":"Everton","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t499.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null},{"id":"64721","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"southampton-manchester_u-1401298","start":"1399816800","home_team":"Southampton","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t8482.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Manchester U","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t20790.png","away_team_short":"Man U","phid":null},{"id":"64716","code":"SOCENGPRE","event_slug":"cardiff-chelsea-1401292","start":"1399816800","home_team":"Cardiff","home_team_phid":null,"home_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t524.png","home_team_short":"","away_team":"Chelsea","away_team_phid":null,"away_team_logo":"\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t497.png","away_team_short":"","phid":null}]}});
```

[Link to pastebin for easier reading of the data](http://pastebin.com/j951y1ju)

Comment: you have an extra semicolon here ```function(jsondata){;```

Comment: What issues are you seeing?  If it wasn't a typo, I agree with @Bonakid

Comment: @VtoCorleone yeah and maybe lack of brackets at the first for loop?

Comment: It is not the semi-colon. I've removed it but it's still not doing what I want it to do.

Comment: Is the the actual URL you're trying to hit?  If it is, try pasting it into your browser and see what happens.  It doesn't return anything.  Make sure you're pointing to a valid endpoint.

Comment: It's not the actual URL because in order to retrieve data you need to call it with an appkey and an appid which are unique to every user. When properly called I get all the upcoming league fixtures with event ids and teams and etc. It does actually work but I don't want to publicly post the valid URL.

Comment: because you have a miscomprehension of the object model ... result.someobj.somearray[i].subobj ... but to shorten this you could set var myarr=result.someobj.somearray ... if you have programmed in C its like nested structs that may contain arrays

Comment: I haven't programmed in C so I'm not entirely sure but I'll try and do something similar.

Comment: you are interpreting the return JSON data all wrong. The return JSON data is not an array, thus you're expression `jsondata.length` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getResults` function to be called after the JSON has been parsed, like so:

```
var myDataVar;
$.ajax({
    url: "URL to JSON file here",
    dataType: "text", //If you get an error here, change the type to "text"
    success: function (data) {
        myDataVar = $.parseJSON(data);
        getResults();
    }
});
```

The above code will save the JSON file's parsed data into a single variable.

It will then call a function to get the results, being this function:

```
function getResults() {
        var fixturesLength = myDataVar.SOCENGPRE.fixtures.length - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i <= fixturesLength; i++) {
            console.log(myDataVar.SOCENGPRE.fixtures[i].id);
        }
    }
```

The above loop will print to the console every one of your fixtures ID's.

**Test data used:**

```
{
    "SOCENGPRE": {
        "league_name": "Barclays Premier League",
        "league_phid": null,
        "league_type": null,
        "fixtures": [{
            "id": "64714",
            "code": "SOCENGPRE",
            "event_slug": "west_ham-tottenham-1401290",
            "start": "1399117500",
            "home_team": "West Ham",
            "home_team_phid": null,
            "home_team_logo": "\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t523.png",
            "home_team_short": "",
            "away_team": "Tottenham",
            "away_team_phid": null,
            "away_team_logo": "\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t498.png",
            "away_team_short": "",
            "phid": null
        }, {
            "id": "64711",
            "code": "SOCENGPRE",
            "event_slug": "manchester_u-sunderland-1401286",
            "start": "1399125600",
            "home_team": "Manchester U",
            "home_team_phid": null,
            "home_team_logo": "\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t20790.png",
            "home_team_short": "Man U",
            "away_team": "Sunderland",
            "away_team_phid": null,
            "away_team_logo": "\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t382.png",
            "away_team_short": "",
            "phid": null
        }, {
            "id": "64712",
            "code": "SOCENGPRE",
            "event_slug": "stoke-fulham-1401288",
            "start": "1399125600",
            "home_team": "Stoke",
            "home_team_phid": null,
            "home_team_logo": "\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t389.png",
            "home_team_short": "",
            "away_team": "Fulham",
            "away_team_phid": null,
            "away_team_logo": "\/\/dxnxhx88pdxyv.cloudfront.net\/logo\/32\/t379.png",
            "away_team_short": "",
            "phid": null
        }]
    }
}
```

**Console results:**

```
64714
64711
64712
```

Comment: I have tried your method and this is what I get :

    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.api.com&leagues=SOCENGPRE&lang=en&format=jsonp&callback=?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Are you wanting to only find results for "SOCENGPRE"? Or all teams?

Comment: SOCENGPRE is the league name. I only want to find the fixture ID and the Home Team name for that fixture (in the SOCENGPRE league).

Comment: I don't think your JSON URL is correct. Please paste it into your URL to see if you can see anything, because its not working for me.

Comment: Try that now. Although, it is very hard to test without the real JSON file.

Comment: Get an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4  which is the parseJSON function.

Comment: Just did a test on my machine and it works perfectly with the code I just edited in my answer.

Comment: When I run it I get the XMLHttpRequest cannot load <URL HERE>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. This always happens to me when I use ajax, for some reason.

Comment: Then honestly, I have no idea. I believe it is something wrong with the generated JSON file since when I tested my code above with the test data, it worked perfectly.